# How do I remove label of code chunk when knitting Rmarkdown document?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

My YAML looks like this:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "AS"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document: bookdown::pdf_document2
bibliography: references.json
header-includes:
   \usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
---
```

and I have a code chunk that looks like this:

```
{r summary table for employment in the agricultural sector, echo =FALSE}
kable(
  agrisum020406,
  booktabs = TRUE,
  digits = 2,
  col.names = c('Working in the Agricultural Sector?', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', '2002-2004', '2002-2006', '2002-2004', '2002-2006'),
  caption = "Changes in Proportion of Workers in the Agricultural Sector, by Gender") %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "2001" = 2, "2003" = 2, "2005" =2, "Change rate (F)" = 2, "Change rate (M)" = 2)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "scale_down"))
```

However, the knitted document displays this:

[image]

How do I remove the '(#tab:summary for employment in the agricultural sector)' section?

Thank you

Comment: Can you make a [mre] in one code block which we can copy and paste to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, however, generally the chunk name does not like spaces, it's better to use dashes to separate words. This seems to work...

Note I removed `bibliography: references.json` from the YAML header to make the answer reproducible.

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "AS"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document: bookdown::pdf_document2

header-includes:
   \usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
---

```{r summary-table-for-employment-in-the-agricultural-sector, echo =FALSE}

library(kableExtra)

kable(
  mtcars[1:5, ],
  booktabs = TRUE,
  digits = 2,
  row.names = "TRUE",
  col.names = c('Working in the Agricultural Sector?', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', '2002-2004', '2002-2006', '2002-2004', '2002-2006'),
  caption = "Changes in Proportion of Workers in the Agricultural Sector, by Gender") |> 
 add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "2001" = 2, "2003" = 2, "2005" =2, "Change rate (F)" = 2, "Change rate (M)" = 2)) |>
 kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "scale_down"))

```
````

[image]